# Убрать страну из вывода геокодера

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api

Коллеги. Пользуюсь скриптом UNISITE. Разработчик то ли помер, то ли некомпетентен.
Вопрос следующего характера: в связи с событиями 24.02 необходимо убрать из вывода результатов геокодера страну, оставив только город, улицу, номер дома.
Сейчас вывод в результатах поиска выглядит как "Ленина улица, Луганск, Украина".
Требуется убрать вывод страны "Ленина улица, Луганск".
Поиск и вывод осуществляется JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var myMap;
      var search_result = [];

      ymaps.ready(function () {

          myMap = new ymaps.Map("mapAddress", {
              center: [<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lon; ?>],
              zoom: 12,
              behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom']
          });
          myMap.controls.add('zoomControl');

      });


      $(document).ready(function(){

       $(document).on('input click','.searchMapAddress', function () {
       
         search_result = [];

              $.getJSON('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=<?php echo $settings["map_yandex_key"]; ?>&format=json&geocode='+$(this).val(), function(data) {

                  $(".SearchAddressResults").html('').hide();

                  for(var i = 0; i < data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember.length; i++) {

                     if(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description !== undefined && data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name !== undefined){

                        var name = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name + ', ' + data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description;

                        var address = '<strong>'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name+'</strong><i>'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description;'</i>'
                        
                     }else if(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description !== undefined){

                        var name = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description;
                        var address = '<strong>'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description+'</strong>';

                     }else if(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name !== undefined){

                        var name = data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name;
                        var address = '<strong>'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name+'</strong>';
                      
                     }

                     if(name){
                      $(".SearchAddressResults").append('<div class="item-city" data-country="'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.description+'" data-address="'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.name+'" data-name="'+name+'" longlat="'+data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[i].GeoObject.Point.pos+'" >'+address+'</div>').show();
                     }

                  }

              });


       });

       $(document).on('click','.SearchAddressResults .item-city', function () {    
       
              var longlat = $(this).attr("longlat").split(" ");
              var data_name = $(this).attr("data-name");

              var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([longlat[1], longlat[0]]);

              $(".searchMapAddress").val(data_name);

              $('input[name="map_lat"]').val(longlat[1]);
              $('input[name="map_lon"]').val(longlat[0]);
              
              myMap.geoObjects.remove();
              myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

              myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
                  var coords = e.get('coords');

                  myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(e.get("coords"));

                  ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function(res) {
                      var first = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                      $(".searchMapAddress").val(first.properties.get('text'));
                      $('input[name="map_lat"]').val(coords[0]);
                      $('input[name="map_lon"]').val(coords[1]);                            
                  });
              });

              myMap.setCenter([longlat[1], longlat[0]], 13);
         
         $(".SearchAddressResults").hide();

       }); 

      });
      </script>
```

Как победить? Возможно, есть какой-то оператор или функция, которые можно добавить?

Comment: Учитывая, что вы и так отображаете карту, использование http-геокодера вместо js-функции geocode() выглядит по меньшей мере странно. В JS на бесплатном тарифе и лимит в 25 раз больше, и реализация. Да и ответ приходит без страны. Пример в песочнице: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode